# Id column regenerated after deploying local sql sever db to sql Azure db?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

Here is my db before I did the deployment:[image]

And below is my db after the deployment:
[image]

You can see here the values in Id column were all regenerated. How can I keep all the values after deployment to Azure sql? I use SSMS 2014 and to deploy, first I generate and deploy schemas and then I exported all data using winzard below:
[image]

Comment: Did you enable Identity Insert in the mappings?

Comment: Hi @BrendanGreen: where can I enable Identity Insert in the mapping? I'm new to this, you can tell

Answer (score 0):

You have probably missed setting the `Enable identity insert` flag when selecting the tables.

When you are selecting the table mappings:

[image: Source Table Mappings]

Hit the **Edit Mappings...** button:

[image: Column Mappings]

And check the `Enable identity insert` option.

You may need to do this for each table mapping.

Comment: Did you choose the "Create destination table", "Delete all rows in destination table", "Append rows to destination table" or "Drop and re-create destination table" in the Column Mappings dialog box? Can you also confirm that the source is a local SQL Server database and the target is Azure SQL Database?